How much power does each component of the ISS use?
The ISS gets 100 kilowatts on average cycling between sunlight and shade. That electricity is divided between different components and systems such as the life support system (CO2 management, heat management,..), scientific equipment, waste management, lighting,.. etc. How many watts does each thing use?

I think the appropriate search term is "powwr budget," but while looking I found this hilariously unhelpful paper where I think the authors had access to all the data you'd want but seem to only want to publish that they Did A Software to it
